# Uncaught reference error prompt

Tags: javascript

Estoy poniendo un código y no sale el prompt, asi que lo pongo en la consola y me salta un error, que esta pasando?

```
var pregunta = propmt("Pregunta")
```

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que estás escribiendo `prompt`? Porque en el código se ve que pusiste `propmt`...

Answer (score 1):

El error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: propmt is not defined

es debido a que has escrito mal el método, lo correcto sería:

`var pregunta = prompt("pregunta")`

Espero que te sirva!